# Yii2 generate dynamic flash message after success

Tags: php, yii2, flash-message

I'm making internet ordering site on Yii2 framework. Now I have page for restaurant page with products, where I can order specified product (can see on screen). How can I implement dynamic success flash image after ordering the product, that will appear on top of page and then fade out? I don't want for page to reload.
[image: order-page]

Answer (score 0):

In your layout view file add (on top of your content):

```
<?=yii\bootstrap\Alert::widget([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'alert-info',
    ],
    'body' => Yii::$app->getSession()->getFlash('success'),
]);?>
```

In your controller

```
public function actionOrder()
{
....
//After order is made
Yii::$app->getSession()->addFlash('success', 'Your Order Has been made successfuly...');
//redirect
...
}
```

Comment: First of all, the way that you offer me -- is not dynamic -- the flash message only shows after refresh the page, and I don't want to refresh page, I want to make DYNAMIC message (as you can see in JIRA, for example, when create issue you can see the success notification that shows immediately and doesn't need to refresh page, and that shows for a couple of seconds and then vanishes). And the second that way I have some exception when render page of restaurant (something about convertation array to string)

Comment: I assume your order request is via ajax.  if so you could include the success-message in your response. then use a  setTimeout() + call back function to display your flash message.